# JS: How to make nested functions?

Tags: javascript, function

I want to make a function in JS with functions inside it and in that function another function or variable. For example with a car, I want to call it like this:

```
var car1 = new car("blue");
var curPosX = car1.position.x;
var curPosY = car1.position.y;

var car2 = new car("red");
car2.motor.start();
car2.motor.moveTo(curPosX, curPosY);
car2.color = "red";
car2.window[0].open();
```

of cource not with the code to make the car move and so, but just an example how I can make this, so I can call it with

```
function.functionInside.anotherFunction();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might find [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would set it up:

```js
var motor = function() {
  this.posX = 0;
  this.posY = 0;
};

motor.prototype.start = function() {
  console.log("motor started!");
};

motor.prototype.moveTo = function(x, y) {
  this.posX = x;
  this.posY = y;
  console.log("motor moved to (" + x + ", " + y + ")");
};

var windowC = function() {
  this.state = false; //closed
};

windowC.prototype.open = function() {
  this.state = true;
  console.log("window opened");
};

var car = function(color) {
  this.color = color;
  this.position = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };
  this.motor = new motor();
  this.window = [new windowC(), new windowC(), new windowC(), new windowC()];
};

var car1 = new car("blue");
var curPosX = car1.position.x;
var curPosY = car1.position.y;

var car2 = new car("red");
car2.motor.start();
car2.motor.moveTo(curPosX, curPosY);
car2.color = "red";
car2.window[0].open();
```

The output:

```
motor started!
motor moved to (0, 0)
window opened
```

[Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) a good read. Classes are supported in ECMA 6, so it'll be easier in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into classes, you can then have objects inside of your main object, on which you can call your functions. ie) a motor object stored inside of your car object.

EDIT:

Here is the simplest example of what you are thinking of.

```
var car = {
    motor: {
        start: function () { return "started motor";}
    }
};

alert(car.motor.start());
```

Comment: @blobliebla I edited my answer to provide some simple code. Read up some more on objects, good luck.

Comment: Thank you, can you please add one more function in the motor object so I know how this works with multiple functions?